# Grouting Porcelain Tile Walls

Tags: tile

When I am applying the grout to the tile walls, most of the grout just falls off the wall and the float while I am trying to apply it. I am using a pre-mix grout, so the consistency is right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The grout should be a creamy peanut butter, so you may need to mix in like 2 tablespoons of water to a **full** or new gallon bucket. These can sit around for years before you get it & can dry out somewhat. You want your squeegee trowel to be mostly flat against the wall to smear the grout on, instead of possibly trying to just stuff the joints.

Comment: I agree with @Iggy about adding a bit more water. Let the grout slake for 10 minutes then see if more water is needed. You **should** stuff the joints; pack them full with the edge of your float, then finish with the float held at a 45° angle for uniform grout depth. Sometimes it helps to mist the joints damp with a spray bottle prior to grout application.